# Error starting audio call using skype web sdk This person can't be reached right now. Please try again later

Tags: office365-restapi, skype-for-business, ucwa, skypedeveloper

I have a web app built using Skype Web SDK. When I try to start an audio call I get an error **"This person can't be reached right now. Please try again later"**. The person whom I am trying to call is available and I am also able to start an IM(chat) with him. Only when I start audio, it throws an error.
I am using Skype For Business Online and not On Premise. The authentication is performed using Azure AD.
I am getting an **InvitationFailed** error with a subcode of **NotAcceptable**

Comment: Is the user also an authenticated user? Does your organization infra support this?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I am using Skype for Business Online and not On Premise. And yes, user is authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

The latest Skype Web SDK requires SfB 2015 CU1+ update on front-end and edge servers. You would also need to whitelist your URL on the server using following powershell command:

```
$x = New-CsWebOrigin -Url “{http://YOUR_URL}”
Set-CsWebServiceConfiguration -Identity “{YOUR_IDENTITY}” CrossDomainAuthorizationList @{Add=$x}
```

Use `Identity` as `global` for global identity

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I am using Skype for Business Online and not On Premise. So there is no question of servers as it will use MS servers.

Comment: You would still need to whitelist the URLs, not sure how would you do it in SfB online.

Comment: I think thats already covered when you use Azure AD for authentication. There is an option to specify URL's which I have already done. I have referred all the resources online regarding the examples for making an audio call. But none of them states doing anything extra rather than just calling the audioService.start() method

Answer (score 0):

A plugin needs to be installed for IE11+ and Edge. Not currently supported in Chrome and Mozilla

[Error accepting audio calls in skype for business web app. Error Failed to parse SessionDescription in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39037004/error-accepting-audio-calls-in-skype-for-business-web-app-error-failed-to-parse/39044361#39044361)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, solved it when I figured out that if you want to call an external user, their skype id is: `sip:skypeusername@skypeids.net`