# Error accepting audio calls in skype for business web app. Error Failed to parse SessionDescription in Chrome

Tags: office365, office365-restapi, skype-for-business, ucwa, skypedeveloper

I have a Skype For Business Online web app. I am using Skype Web SDK and Azure AD for authentication. On making a audio call from Lync, I sucessfully receive notification in the web app. But the audio call soon gets disconnected. Error is **Failed to parse SessionDescription. candidate:a5BpIVxQzQh5t/7CqfgBOQeCbDFb0l/mEzYbPkw96vg 1 1V4ajHJQOLI2T9wGQfzL1g UDP 0.830 172.51.21.32 24068  Expects at least 8 fields.** The name of error comes as **OperationError**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the Skype Web SDK doesn't support audio calling to or from Chrome. If you try the same scenario using your web app in one of the supported browsers (IE 11+, Microsoft Edge, or Safari) it should work. The Web SDK team is hoping to add AV support for Chrome soon. The list of browsers the SDK currently supports is here under "Skype for Business Web App Plug-in/ORTC Support". https://msdn.microsoft.com/skype/websdk/GettingStarted

Comment: Hi. Thanks a lot. Actually i searched about the plugin, but it seems I was unable to find this specific one. I think I installed some other plugin. The audio now works in IE11.